# How to get autocomplete text box value in angularJS with DevExtreme

Tags: devextreme

Trying to submit an autocomplete search box with the text that's typed into the box. I can use `onValueChanged` but it fires every keypress. I need to search when enter is pressed. I've tried a few things but can't work it out. This is part of a dxToolbar:

```
{
  location: 'after',
  widget: 'dxAutocomplete',
  options: {
    width: '340px',
    placeholder: 'Enter title, category or identifier',
    dataSource: PageAutoCompleteDataSource($http),
    bindingOptions: {
      searchText: 'text'
    },
    onChange: function(e){
      console.log('Value searched ' + $scope.searchText);
      DevExpress.ui.notify("Searching for " + $scope.searchText);

    }
  }
}
```

Never mind about the datasource etc. I just need to know how to get the current value in any of the onXX events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the [onEnterKey](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxAutocomplete/Configuration/#onEnterKey) event handler:

```
$scope.autocompleteOptions = {
    //...
    onEnterKey: function(e) {
        var selectedValue = e.component.option("value");
        DevExpress.ui.notify("Searching for " + selectedValue);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zNND5s44YKPra49uCUe6?p=preview)

Comment: yep that's right, but it's the `e.component.option("value")` that I couldn't work out from docs. Thanks.